# How to create dynamic permalink URLs from $_POST data

Tags: php, forms, url, post, clean-urls

Is it possible to generate nice dynamic/permalink URLs based on $_POST submission form data?
Essentially I'd like the page.php I direct a form to - to create it's own URL from data that's in the $_POST array.

I've only seen methods to create dynamic/permalink URLs from within frameworks or based on SQL database rows/columns.
Whereas, I'd like to go from **mywebsite.com/index.php** to **mywebsite.com/[topic-keyword-from-form-submission]/**

A more direct or likely example would be:
**mywebsite.com/european-union/**

On the index.php page are various category style keywords as buttons within forms - no open text input boxes. 
Are there any security concerns/considerations if the above is achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start to use mvc. Most framework now are also using MVC. I would also suggest to start using a framework as else you will have to build a routing system each time which takes up time you could have used somewhere else.

I would suggest laravel :)

In shorts it's possible but not worth the time.